# I want to override some methods of SearchResultsPortlet.java. Liferay/dxp-7.4.13-u76

Tags: java, liferay, osgi

I am trying to achieve this through liferay module fragment. Is it possible?

I created a fragment and created the packages with exact names as they have in source code.

I created a `public class CustomPortlet extends SearchResultsPortlet`.

I implemented a `@Override public void render(RenderRequest rq,RenderResponse re ) throws IOException,PortletException {log.info("Overriden"); System.out.println("Overriden"); super.render(rq,re);}`

I also tried with and without @Component annotation in my subclass.
But osgi is not registering my component.
What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add properties inside  @Component annotation? Shouldn't the subclass inherit the superclass's annotations? I also made changes in a few jsp files, they are reflected in the portlet.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be several issues:

- Fragment bundles can contain JSPs but not code, Components, etc.
- Just because you implement a subclass of a portlet does not mean that it'll be wired instead of the superclass component

Instead of providing a full tutorial how to do it: My recommendation is to check for a solution to the underlying problem. You have chosen a solution strategy (override a portlet), which [may or may not be the proper solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) for the underlying problem: Liferay's Search framework provides a lot of extension points that are meant for extention rather than code that needs to be replaced

If you want to stick with your solution, search for "marketplace override", which basically allows you to replace built-in components. I'd not recommend it though, as you'll have to do a three-way-merge any time you update and the original component has changed. That's a lot of maintenance burden, and I assume that there must be simpler solutions (I just don't know your underlying problem)

Comment: Thanks for that answer Olaf. So, I found a workaround to my problem. I would create my own portlets for search functionality. That way I would be able to build my queries and get search results based on that. I could not however find a good source on how to do that. I mean build a query that should return me all hits related to keyword "test" whether Pages, JournalArticles, Users, BlogEntries etc. I could also use portal-search-rest api to get search hits, but I am unable to build a request body that would return a response body with all the hits.